# Avoid repetitive functions in a controller file inside an express REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have a bunch of controller functions that do exactly the same thing: call a service function in another file of the same name. For the sake of example, I'll provide just two functions, but imagine there are several of them.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userService = require('./user.service');
const authorize = require('_helpers/authorize');

// routes
router.post('/authenticate', authenticate);     
router.post('/create', create);
// ...
// ( it goes on like this )
// ...
module.exports = router;



function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    userService.authenticate(req.body)
        .then(user => user ? res.json(user) : res.status(400).json({ message: 'Error.' }))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}

function create(req, res, next) {
    userService.create(req.body)
        .then(user => user ? res.json(user) : res.status(400).json({ message: 'Error.' }))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
// ...
// ( it goes on like this )
```

Is there a way in Javascript to avoid such repetitive code? ( I'm not new to programming but I'm a newcomer to Javascript ). I was thinking about automating this code generation with vim macros but maybe there's some package or feature in the language that can make this code look less verbose, maybe some sort of metaprogramming.

Answer (score 1):

Create two utility functions, like this

- `handleUser` which takes a `res` object and returns another function that takes `user`. This will allow you to inject `res` easily
- `handleError` which takes a `next` callback and return another function that takes `err`

---

```
const handleUser = res => user =>
  user ? res.json(user) : res.status(400).json({ message: 'Error.' });

const handleError = next => err => next(err);

const authenticate = (req, res, next) =>
  userService.authenticate(req.body)
  .then(handleUser(res)).catch(handleError(next));

const create = (req, res, next) => userService.create(req.body)
  .then(handleUser(res)).catch(handleError(next));
```